# Simple python localhost proxy - almost working

Tags: python, sockets, proxy

I'm working on a slightly larger project of my own and I need to make a localhost proxy in python.

The way I wrote mine is that there's a TCP server (using socket and SOCK_STREAM) on port 8080 on the localhost. It accepts a request from the local host, using slicing, string.find(), and gethostbyname() finds that target IP, so it opens up another TCP socket, sends the request and recv's a reply. After that, it relays the reply back to the localhost proxy which in turn throws it back at the browser.

This is the code with ample debugging messages and a debug file to collect the requests of the browser and the replies received back (also note this is just a prototype, hence the limited for loop instead of a while 1 loop):

```
import socket

local = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

f = open('test.txt', 'a')
local.bind(('localhost', 8080))
local.listen(5)
for i in xrange(20):
    print '=====%d=====\n' % i
    out = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    data, addr = local.accept()
    print 'Connection accepted'
    buffer = data.recv(4096)
    print 'data recieved'
    f.write('=============================================================\n')
    f.write(buffer)
    end = buffer.find('\n')

    print buffer
    #print buffer[:end]
    host = buffer[:end].split()[1]
    end = host[7:].find('/')

    print host[7:(end+7)]
    host_ip = socket.gethostbyname(host[7:(end+7)])
    #print 'remote host: ' + host + ' IP: ' + host_ip
    print 'sending buffer to remote host'
    out.connect((host_ip, 80))
    out.sendall(buffer)
    print 'recieving data from remote host'
    reply = out.recv(4096)
    out.close()
    print 'data recieved from remote host'
    f.write('+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++\n')
    f.write(reply)
    f.write('\n\n\n')
    print 'sending data back to local host'
    data.sendall(reply)
    print 'data sent'
local.close()
out.close()    
f.close()
```

Now my problem is that it seems to work fine for the first few requests, it gets the html and a few images but at some point it always stops at the "data received" point and quits, because it gets no data ie. the buffer is empty. The browser still shows it's loading elements of the page, but when it stops and I look at the text log file, I see that the buffer was empty, meaning that the browser didn't submit anything to the proxy?

I am guessing that the issue lies somewhere in how a browser submits requests and my script not reacting properly to this behavior.

I know I could use the Twist framework, however I want to learn to write this kinda stuff myself. I've been reading about SocketServer and I might use that, but I have no clue if it'll solve the issue because frankly, I don't really understand what's causing the issue here. Is my script too slow for the browser? Do servers send more than one answer and my receiving socket should listen for more packets? Is my buffer size (4096) too small?

I'd really appreciate a nudge in the right direction.

Thanks!

Comment: Ok, I just did a few tests. I increased the buffer of the out socket to 65536, so that I could get all the bigger images and it seems to have relayed a few more replies back to the browser. However, now I'm getting an index error in line 23, further indicating that the variable buffer, which receives GETs from the local browser is simply... empty.

Comment: I also rewrote the script just now to use threads and a Queue. I used the queue.get(True, 10) function to raise exceptions if a thread cannot get anything from the queue for 10 seconds. _Guess what?_ It raises exceptions. It would appear that for some reason, the local socket bound to localhost is not .accept()'ing any connections from localhost, hence it cannot obtain localhost's outbound requests, which causes all the problems. This is where I have to leave it for today due to school.

Comment: you seem to be on the right path - try using "127.0.0.1" instead of "localhost" if you're on Win OS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I managed to answer my question. What I suspected previously was partly true - the browser was waiting for something and that something was replies.

I fired up wire shark, did some experiments and I noticed that my proxy makes a lot of ugly TCP RST appear in wireshark. I also noticed that in a normal connection, a lot of the server replies are split up into a few different packets.

Basically, my program wasn't getting all the answers back from the server because the out.recv was getting just one part of the reply. The obvious answer was to make a loop and listen for all the replies. I found the perfect solution at http://www.binarytides.com/receive-full-data-with-the-recv-socket-function-in-python/ .

I quickly recoded my program a bit and it works like a charm. Now I can move on forward with my whole project.

I hope this might help anyone else in the future with a similar issue.